# Draw thinner line than 1 px using paint in android

Tags: android, paint

I am using Paint in my app to draw lines.I have used StrokeWidth(0),even though,i feel line is thicker.So please let me know how to reduce the thickness of the line.

```
            Paint paint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
            Typeface typeFace = Typeface.create("sans-serif", Typeface.NORMAL);
            Typeface typeFaceBold = Typeface.create("sans-serif", Typeface.BOLD);
            paint.setTextSize(mFontSize);
            paint.setTypeface(typeFace);
            paint.setColor(mFontNormalColor);
            paint.setAntiAlias(true);
            paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
            paint.setStrokeWidth(2 / getResources().getDisplayMetrics().scaledDensity);
            paint.setTextAlign(Align.CENTER);
```

Comment: I want a thinnest line which is visible,this is my task :(

Comment: Yes, and as mentioned in that answer and in the documentation, `setStrokeWidth(0)` ("hairline mode") is as thin as possible.